# What is a good implementation of a timer for an embedded system?

Tags: c

I have been looking at various ways to implement a timer or alarm that will executes a cleanup function for a program in an embedded system with minimal resources.

Essentially, I'd like the function to be executed when the system is under minimal load, minimal network activity and/or when a period of time has been reached.

I think multi-threading a timer isn't a viable option and probably overkill and a timer executing when the system is busy.. is probably not a good option either.

Ideas anyone?

**EDIT:**

Running OpenWRT and busybox

Comment: What operating system does it have?  If there is none, how hard would it be to add the cleanup function to the main idle loop?

Comment: Adding the cleanup function to the idle loop doesn't seem like that is low-overhead and smart in a resource restricted system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using variables and a timer to solve my issues.  The timer executes, but based off of the variables - I either execute the code.. or not.